# Why does random in django rest serializer always return the same field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a simple serializer

```
class Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, default='someName')
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=random.randrange(100, 200))
```

And when I create multiple instances of the serializer it always returns the same field

```
a = Serializer(data={})
a.is_valid(data={})
data = a.data
data['id'] // return  for example 150
 
b = Serializer(data={})
b.is_valid(data={})
b_data = b.data
b_data['id'] // return also 150
```

Why it happens? How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your `default` like this instead:

```py
default=lambda: random.randrange(100, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the default id in your serializer class is defined once and it's equal to 150.
It's like writing

```
id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=150)
```

If you want the id to be random you should use `random.randrange(100, 200)` when creating an istance.

Comment: I do not want to explicitly specify random when creating an instance

Comment: In this case GProst's solution should does the trick

Comment: Serializers have very strange logic. Thanks :)